# How do I capture a list with Regex inside a group of parentheses

Tags: regex

I need to monitor SQL queries for certain words. I am trying to find a way to capture a comma separated list of quoted names inside of parentheses using regex.  There might be several instances of quoted names, but I am only looking for those where they are contained in the parentheses and specific to the person search as seen in the example below.

Here is a sample query:

```
Select Time, date, metric, user, status, person
from person table
where user = 'Me' and status = 'Active' and person in ('Jones', 'Taylor', 'Wright')
```

I only want to capture Jones, Taylor and Wright. I don't want to capture Me or Active.

When I have tried to use `\'(?<person>(\w+,?)+)(\')+`  it does a great job but includes Me and Active.  If I add `(in\s+\()\'(?<person>(\w+,?)+)(\')+` it only captures Jones - but does not include Taylor and Wright.

Comment: What programming language do you use? Named capture groups are a hint for `PCRE`.

Comment: `(?:\G(?!^)',\s*|\bin\s+\()'(?<person>\w+)` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage the `\G` functionality as in

```
(?:\(|\G(?!\A)[^()]+?)\K'([^']+)'
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/W7hwt0/1).

Comment: This works great and answers the question - but if the query was changed to person = 'Jones' without a list, is there a way to make the non-capturing group at the beginning more generic to also include this possibility?  Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Spodg: Yes. But provide some other examples or post another question.